# How to re-define a method in a "javascript class"

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Please run the following code snippet <sup>1</sup> and see what is happening in JS console:

My questions are regarding the last line in the snippet:

1. Why is `F.prototype.method;` changed?
2. How should I redefine `Fcustom.prototype.method` in order to not change `F.prototype.method`?

**Note:** I am using jQuery and underscore to extend the function.

---

- <sup>1</sup> Test code snippet:

  ```
  var F = function () {};
  F.prototype.method = function () {
      // some code
  }

  F.prototype.method; // it shows "some code"


  Fcustom = $.extend(true, F, {});

  _.extend(Fcustom.prototype, {
  method: function () {
      // other code
      }
  });

  Fcustom.prototype.method; // it shows "other code"

  F.prototype.method; // it shows "other code" instead of "some code" Why?
  ```

Comment: Do you want to clone the function `F` to `Fcustom`?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot clone functions...

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = { myMethod : function() { 
              //some code
          }
};

var newObj = $.extend(true, {}, obj);

newObj.myMethod = function (){       
   //new method
};

newObj.myMethod();  //should call the new method
```

While,

```
obj.myMethod(); //still calls the old "//some code"
```

---

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/K8g8q/):

Comment: I think you meant to swap the arguments to `$.extend`.

Comment: @pimvdb: In short. Yes. But it thought it would be better to demonstrate that the **first argument is the target of the change**. While the original remains untouched. All without directly tampering with `prototype`.

Comment: I understand but your last comment of the first snippet is not correct, I'm afraid.

Comment: @pimvdb: I'm sorry I already made an edit to my comment. The way I see it - OP is trying to 1. get a clone of the original 2. then change its implementation. I hope I haven't gone wrong with that much, right?

Comment: You're correct :) But my point is that `newObj.myMethod === obj.myMethod` so both calls refer to the "some code" function.

Comment: @pimvdb: You were right. And I too was right in my understanding but did it wrong. Stupid me. I have edited my answer. Thanks :)